# Service using too much memory in android resulting Force stopping

Tags: android, android-service, eclipse-memory-analyzer

In my application,from a Service, i am entering data into database and collecting those datas in some Bean class object in a repeated time interval using a Timer. I am using that instance in my Activity to get the data. The system worked fine first. But the service keeps on consuming more memory. At some point it reached almost 30 MB. Eventually service is closed by the ActivityManager and statement issued is:**Force stopping service ServiceRecord** .Why service consumes so much memory,but the Application ran in just 100KB or so. I have used the MAT in eclipse, but it does not give a clear picture which is consuming so much memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have memory leak somewhere. Check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk), it gives good information on how to manage memory in Android.